# ERROR while executing my code programmed in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I got this error when i'm trying to run my code by the statement "LauncherImpl".
Has anyone an idea how to fix it?

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class application.view1controller (in unnamed module @0x3fb6a447) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.application to unnamed module @0x3fb6a447
    at application.view1controller.main(view1controller.java:24)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application application.view1controller

    package application;

import com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class view1controller extends Application {

    public void start(Stage view1) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view1.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        view1.setScene(scene);
        view1.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(view1controller.class, SplashScreen.class, args);
    }
```

VM Arguments:
--module-path "D:\Fabian Boni\Documents\eclipse workspace\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics

Comment: why don't you use `launch(args);` directly in the main function ?

Comment: If you want to use a preloader then set the `javafx.preloader` system property before calling `Application#launch(...)`. Don't use the internal `LauncherImpl` class.